# How to do field selection on find() in the mongodb native driver?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using the mongodb native driver for node.js and can't get to work the field selection. What I want to do is to limit fields to name. I do not want the 'last' in the output.

I am doing this:

```
db.collection("test").find({},[{'name':true,'last':false}]).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.dir(results);
});
```

But the log prints:

```
[ { _id: 524b53588aa4f388de1c2ddb },
  { _id: 524b53548aa4f388de1c2dda } ]
```

So there is no `name` in the output.

---

**Update**:
I have tried an object instead of array -- did not work. The reason is really mixing inclusion and exclusion.  You can't mix it. When I only had `"name":true` it worked.

Comment: Try passing 1 instead of true. And also, don't use an array. Pass an object {name:1, last:1}

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The field selection argument to `find` is an object, not an array.  And you can't mix field inclusion and exclusion (except for `_id`), so it should be:

```
db.collection("test").find({}, {'name': true}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.dir(results);
});
```

Comment: I'm getting `toArray()` is not a function. But when I do pass the function as a third argument to `find()` I get back all the fields in the response.

Answer (score 30):

If you are using latest mongodb 3.0 nodejs driver, then try this code:

```
db.collection('test').find({}).project({name: 1, last: 1}).toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. ))

Comment: the official mongodb documentation state a wrong syntax. The above answer (using .project({fields:value}) works like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

The recommended way of doing this in v3.0 is with the projection field in the options object:

```
db.collection('test').find({}, {projection: {name: 1}}).toArray()
```

As mentioned in the accepted answer, you still cannot mix inclusion and exclusion.

See: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Collection.html#find

Answer (score 0):

Omit the array:

```
db.collection("test").find({},{'name':true,'last':false}).toArray(function(err, results) {
    console.dir(results);
});
```