# How to get the Specific information inside Record from mongo using node js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  "Name": "lokesh",
  "Courses": [
    {
      "Name": "EC",
      "Faculity": "Priyadharshini",
      "ExamDate": "Thu Aug 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
      "Marks": [
        {
          "testCode": "EC-01",
          "testMarks": "98"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "EC-02",
          "testMarks": "94"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Name": "CS",
      "Faculity": "Rama",
      "ExamDate": "Thu Aug 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)",
      "Marks": [
        {
          "testCode": "CS-01",
          "testMarks": "96"
        },
        {
          "testCode": "CS-02",
          "testMarks": "96"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "StudentCode": "Software"
}
```

In Above Object how to access to get only **"CS"** or **"EC"** Object inside the course object ***without any unwanted information***

I tried this command in **mongo shell**

```
db.studentMarksPortal.find({"Name":'lokesh'},{"Courses":{$elemMatch:{"Name": 'EC'}}})
```

And the **Output** is this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aaa0005572a4c172030c852"), "Courses" : [ { "Name" : "EC", "Faculity" : "Priyadharshini", "ExamDate" : "Thu Aug 27 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)", "Marks" : [ { "testCode" : "EC-01", "testMarks" : "98" }, { "testCode" : "EC-02", "testMarks" : "96" }, { "testCode" : "Final", "testMarks" : "99" } ] } ] }
```

***But*** when I try in **Node Js** as below

```
db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses":{$elemMatch:{"Name": studentCourse}}}).toArray( 
                function(findErr, result){
                    if (findErr) reject(findErr);
                    client.close();
                    console.log(result);
                    resolve(result);
                }
            );
     });
```

it is returning complete record of lokesh why? Can anybody help me how can I get only selected course?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998238/how-to-do-field-selection-on-find-in-the-mongodb-native-driver

Comment: Are you using the native mongo driver or Mongoose ? `Mongoose` could make this process and more a bit easier if you're unfamiliar

Comment: Native mongo driver

Comment: I don't know anything about mongoose can you help me native mongo how to do that?

Comment: I have updated my answer : `db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses":{$elemMatch:{"Name": studentCourse}}}).project({ Name: 1, Marks: 1});`

Comment: I have added an answer for you, check it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the find filters on your query.

`db.collection(collectionName).find({'Courses'}, { "_id": 0, "Name": 1 });`

This specific example is using the native mongo library but the same pretext will apply to others. Mongoose i believe is `select`.

The second object is the filters, for example I don't want `_id` in this case which I want returned with `Name`, and Name is set to true.

I haven't tested this but it should be what you're looking for :
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/#suppress-id-field

The recommended method from Mongo is `$projection`
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

The fields to return in the query. Object of fields to include or exclude (not both), `{'a':1}`

Your query will be :

`db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses.Name":studentCourse}).project({ Name: 1, Marks: 1});`

Will find courses with name `ECE`, and return the `Name` with the `Marks` You're looking for..

Comment: what if there are multiple students having similar courses

Comment: It will return them all.. If you don't want them all you can use `limit` to limit results, or filter further ?

Comment: i don't all of them i want to get only selected students's selected course only because i'm using select in html when user selects a student it will show particular student courses only. Also Course is select if user selects course it should return student related course and course related marks

Comment: I don't see what the problem is then... `db.collection.find( { "Courses": { Name: "ECE" } }, { "_id": 0, "Name": 1, "Marks": 1 } )` Updated answer..

Comment: it is returning only name

Comment: @LokeshKanumoori try this last one : `db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses.Name":studentCourse}).project({ Name: 1, Marks: 1});`

If it fails i will create some sample data and do it

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it is all courses this is query i used
`db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses.Name":studentCourse}).project({ Name: 1, Courses: 1})`

I want only one course object i.e. if I select **CS** it should return only CS object can you please help with that?

Comment: @LokeshKanumoori you can use the limit option in the query ie : `db.collection(collectionName).find({"Name":studentName},{"Courses.Name":studentCourse}, {limit : 1}).project({ Name: 1, Courses: 1})` That should do it.

Comment: it is returning complete array

Answer (score 0):

Try with this :

```
db.collection(collectionName).find({
    Name: studentName,
    Courses: {
        $elemMatch: {
            Name: studentCourse
        }
    }
}, {"Courses.$": 1})
```

The `$elemMatch` operator need to be in the filter and not in the projection

Comment: Still it is giving complete student obj

Comment: still same @Nicolas

Comment: Actually i just want ECE course object only if query for ECE i don't want any other object in that array like CS

Comment: Yeah i understand what you want as result. It's weird, I have the exact same query in my project and it return my nested document

Comment: nested document means?

Comment: Your "Courses" field is an array of nested documents, or subdocument, and yes it return only the value in the array that I match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167651/discussion-between-lokesh-kanumoori-and-nicolas).

Answer (score 0):

Your query will look like this:

```
db.course.aggregate([
{$redact:{
   $cond:{
        if:{$eq:["$Name","ECE"]},
        then:"$$PRUNE" ,
        else:"$$DESCEND"
   }    
 }}
])
```

You can pass on `Name` field for equality check and it will filter documents accordingly. In the above example, I removed all documents where `Courses.Name` is `ECE`

[image]

Comment: Can you pease explain me actually new to mongo so i don't know about your answer please explain me

Comment: I just wrote the Mongo query for you that actually gives output for your requirement. I dont have mongoose experience either.

Comment: is it mongoose query or mongo?

Comment: Mongoosejs is a mongodb object modeling for node.js. I dont have node.js experience.
It is Mongo query. There's no stuff so called `mongoose query`
If you know node.js and u have this mongo query, you should be able to proceed from here.

Comment: ok but what is redact, prune and descend all these.
I don't know anything can you explain me?

Comment: Take your time and read them here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/